# Cosmos DB input binding for Azure function cannot cast System.String to System.Guid

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following Azure Function

```
[FunctionName("AllProducts")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "marketplace",
            collectionName: "products",
            SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM product",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString")] IEnumerable<Product> products,
        ILogger log)
    {
        ...some magic here
    }
```

It is running on .NET Core 3.1 with Azure Functions runtime 3.x.
The `Product.ID` property is `Guid`. When I send a request to the function I get `500` and in the log stream I see the following message:

> Executed 'AllProducts' (Failed,
> Id=147b3de4-c6f1-445c-80ba-28e75a25ed31, Duration=48ms)Could not cast
> or convert from System.String to System.Guid.

Is there a way to convert from string to guid without chaning my models?

The model class is as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your model class as well? Asking to make sure your Id property is not conflicting with the auto generated id property of the document.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Turns out it is true that the Id property was conflicting with the auto generated id property :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your Id property is not conflicting with the auto generated id property of the document.
You can change the property to PropertyID in the document and serialize it accordingly

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("PropertyID")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did exactly that and it started working. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB has auto generated ID for each document. In my case the auto generated id looks like `<Discriminator>|<Auto-generated guid>`. This made it unable for the binding to parse the ID it received as a guid. I changed the `Product.ID` property to `Product.ProductID` and after that it started working.